# Pygame Type error: Argument must be a rect style object

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

I created this class so I could work with better

```
class Block:
  def __init__(self, top, left):
    self.Rect = pygame.Rect((top,left),(10,10))
```

Then I wanted to create a simple function that clips a rect like so

```
def clip(rect_obj):
  return pygame.Rect.clip(rect_obj)
```

But when I pass the rect into my function I get the error in the headline. I even printed the type

```
my_block = Block()
print(type(my_block.Rect))    --> <Class Pygame.Rect>
my_rect = clip(my_block.Rect) --> TypeError: Argument must be a rect style Object
```

I want to know if there is a difference between a Rect Style Object and a Rect Object because I'm so confused. Also would drawing rects on a screen be the best way to layout a tic tac toe GUI or is it simpler to draw lines.

Comment: You're passing a class when a rect object is expected.  A rect object is essentially a 4-value tuple.  Try ```my_rect = clip((10,10,10,10))```.  Also, you need to pass a top and left parameter to Block() when you instantiate it, so your call first line in the main block should be ```my_block = Block(10,10)``` or somesuch..

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm not saying that a python.Rect object is not a valid argument, but when the OP calls clip, he's passing a Class as observed in the output of his ```print(type(my_block.Rect))```.  See the examples ot how clip is called [here](https://github.com/search?q=pygame.Rect.clip&type=Code&l=Python).  Basically, the call should be ```my_rect = clip(my_block.Rect(left, top, width, height))``` as noted [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

Comment: @Fubar `my_block.Rect` is an instance of `pygame.Rect`. `Rect` is an attribute. The name is misleading, but it is a `pygame.Rect` object. Note, the scope of the attribute `Rect` is `Block`. The scope of the rectangle class `Rect` is `pygame`

Comment: @Rabbid76 regardless, what's being sent to the clip() routine is a class... from the OP, ```print(type(my_block.Rect))    --> <Class Pygame.Rect>```

Comment: @Fubar No. You are wrong again. `my_block.Rect` is an object. `pygame.Rect` is a class. `my_block.Rect` is an instance of `pygame.Rect`, because of  `self.Rect = pygame.Rect((top,left),(10,10))` and `my_block = Block()`

Comment: Pleas show the original code, because `my_block = Block()` won't work at all. The constructor of `Block` has 3 arguments (`def __init__(self, top, left):`)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
my_block = Block(25, 25)
my_block1 = Block(25, 25)
my_block1.Rect.clip(my_block.Rect)
```

Note: `clip()` is a `pygame.Rect` method.
Also, maybe it would be easier to inherit from `pg.Rect`:

```
class Block(pygame.Rect):
    def __init__(self, rect):
        super().__init__(rect)
```

and add attributes you need. Surely there are better ways, this is just an idea.

Comment: Thank you. I like this idea

Answer (score 0):

The error is the line `pygame.Rect.clip(rect_obj)`

> ```py
> def clip(rect_obj):
>    return pygame.Rect.clip(rect_obj)
> ```

This line does not make any sense at all, because [`pygame.Rect.clip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clip) is a instance method.   `pygame.Rect.clip()`:

> Returns a new rectangle that is cropped to be completely inside the argument Rect. If the two rectangles do not overlap to begin with, a Rect with 0 size is returned.

The mehtod intersects 2 [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects:

```py
rect_1 = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 20, 20)
rect_2 = pygame.Rect(10, 10, 30, 30)
rect_and = rect_1.clip(rect_2 )
```

`rect_and` is the rectangle at (10, 10), with a size of (10, 10).

Probably you try to set the clipping region to the display surface. This can be done by [`pygame.Surface.set_clip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html). For instance:

```py
screen = display.set_mode((width, height))

clip_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
screen.set_clip(clip_rect )
```